# Add new boolean field required with default value in Odoo

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo-10

I'm editing the res.users model and I need to add a new field like that:

```
class UsersMod(models.Model):

    _inherit = "res.users"

    session_status = fields.Boolean(default=False, required=True)
```

And I get the next warning:

```
2019-11-13 19:17:46,863 29638 INFO PruebaRecaudo3 odoo.sql_db: bad query: ALTER TABLE "res_users" ALTER COLUMN "session_status" SET NOT NULL
2019-11-13 19:17:46,864 29638 WARNING PruebaRecaudo3 odoo.models: WARNING: unable to set column session_status of table res_users not null !
Try to re-run: openerp-server --update=module
If it doesn't work, update records and execute manually:
ALTER TABLE res_users ALTER COLUMN session_status SET NOT NULL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andres/Proyectos/Tutorial/odoo/models.py", line 2543, in _auto_init
    cr.execute('ALTER TABLE "%s" ALTER COLUMN "%s" SET NOT NULL' % (self._table, name))
  File "/home/andres/Proyectos/Tutorial/odoo/sql_db.py", line 154, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/Proyectos/Tutorial/odoo/sql_db.py", line 231, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
IntegrityError: column "session_status" contains null values
```

**Note:** When I use:

```
session_status = fields.Boolean(default=True, required=True)
```

I don't get any problem

Answer (score 1):

"IntegrityError: column "session_status" contains null values" its because you set required=True  in "session_status" MODEL, its mean column "session_status" cannot contain NULL values. But in your table there's a record where "session_status" value is NULL. To fix this issue, you have 2 option.

Option 1:
Update value manually in res_users.session_status.

Option 2:
set required in XML with attrs.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have a question, I set default = False, and I think all records should have been set to False but not. However, when I set True, all records were set to True. So, Can you explain me that please??

Comment: DEFAULT its for new record only... and, the old record will still contains "NULL" value

Comment: I am not sure what you say, because when I set TRUE old and new records set True.

Comment: @AndresRamos I think Odoo stores False as Null in the database, but setting a boolean field as required?!! odoo will force to set it to True always or i'm wrong?!!

Comment: Hi @CharifDZ , thanks for your reply. Odoo does not store False as Null. I think maybe it could be because of the ORM, because I did it in SQL in Postgres with old records, I added a new non-null column with the default value FALSE and it had no problems and all the records were set to False

Comment: @AndresRamos but why makinh a boolean field required it will be always True?

Comment: @CharifDZ I don't understand you, I never said it will always be true

Answer (score 0):

May be You are trying to create form view by using `ir.actions.act_window`, which is not valid.

use `model="ir.ui.view"` instead

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't understand what you said. I am not trying to create a new view. Only I added a new boolean field to res.users model and I want to set FALSE to all records.